# Почему не работает данный SQL запрос

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS total FROM (`i_com`) RIGHT OUTER JOIN `i_all` ON `i_all`.`id_all` = `i_com`.`id_all` WHERE `category` IN ('seo', 'sites', 'ide', 'des', 'javascript_jquery', 'php_sql') AND `deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `total` desc
```

> `#1046 - No database selected`

В таблице i_all содержатся материалы сайта, в таблице i_com комментарии. Связаны между собой через id материала (id_all). Я пытаюсь получить список материалов, отсортированных по количеству комментариев. Если есть другие идеи - предложите. Или придется на РНР сортировать?

Comment: `>_<` вы три слова перевести не в состоянии?

Answer (score 2):

В phpmyadmin'е ткните на базу данных слева и **в ней** повторите запрос.

В php при успешном коннекте делать ничего не надо. Если вы и там не выбрали БД, пишите

```
FROM `database_name`.`i_com`
```

Comment: Правильно. Дело в том, что с РНР этот код(запрос) выполняется без ошибок а в phpmyadmin'е с ошибкой. Но суть не в этом. Почему возвращается 1 результат? Ожидается около 30 с сортировкой по ...

Comment: Покажите как формируете php при запросе?!

Comment: @jfjgjkslxd потому что в PHP вы выбрали базу, а в phpmyadmin  видимо нет. сначала выберите, потом попробуйте запрос.